# $f(x,y,z)=3\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2x^3-2y^3-2z^3$, $(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$ has only one extreme value $\log(\frac{3}{e^2})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that the extremum value of $$\displaystyle f(x,y,z)=3\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2x^3-2y^3-2z^3$$
$(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$ is $\displaystyle \log(\frac{3}{e^2})$

Attempt:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=0, \\
\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=0, \\
\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}=0, 
\end{cases}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 
\left \lbrace {\matrix{
\left(\dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}-x^2 \right)=0, &(1) \\
\left(\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}-y^2 \right)=0, &(2) \\
\left(\dfrac{z}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}-z^2 \right)=0. &(3) \\
 }}\right.
$$
Adding them we get $x+y+z = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$ 
 Thus, points are $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ 
But none of them are extrema because $(df)^2 = -18(dx)^2+6(dy)^2+6(dz)^2$ [For $(1,0,0)$] does not keep the same sign for this set. Checking with the matrix method gave the same result with all 3 minors being less than $0$.

Thanks for your response!
[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565223/displaystyle-fx-y-z-3logx2y2z2-2x2-2y3-2z3-x-y-z-neq0-0-0-h)
In this, one of the powers of x is 2 instead of 3 in the question. Also in the answer given none of the cases of extrema give the value of function as $log(\frac{3}{e^2})$

Solution 
Considering point $(\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}})$ The desired result is obtained. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Question. Would your function be $f(x,y,z)=3log(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2x^2-2y^3-2z^3$ or $f(x,y,z)=3log(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2x^3-2y^3-2z^3$?

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565223/19266

Comment: No it does not have an answer to the question

Comment: @EliasCosta I have corrected the power

Comment: Are you sure about your points? You get that $x = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ and the same for $y$ and $z$, so $x=y=z$ which then gives you that $x = \frac{1}{3x^2}$, so $x = (1/3)^{1/3}$. You do not get the correct extreme value from this, so either your original function is wrong or the proposed extreme value is wrong.

Comment: Bravo! You do get $log(3/e^2)$ from this value. That is the solution to the answer thanks

Comment: To those who closed the question, the linked question is different and has an incorrect power in the question so it would be impossible to prove it, so have asked this question separately and provided the answer as well